# Data from relationship won't display, no errors

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table that contains tag_id's and contact_id's, I managed to be able to get the contacts that have a particular tag_id, but I can't get the data to actually display.

Taggings.php

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Contact', 'contact_id', 'ID');
}

public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
}
```

Contact.php

```
public function taggings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Taggings', 'contact_id', 'ID');
    }
```

In the controller

```
$contacts = Taggings::with('contact')->where('tag_id', $tag->id)->get();
```

In the template

```
@foreach ($contacts as $contact)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $contact->fname !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $contact->lname !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $contact->email !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This causes nothing to display, if I just try to output {{ $contact }} I get all the data, but trying to display only certain columns from the contacts leads to nothing to be displayed.  I "can" display columns from the taggings table, but that's not what I need.

I'm pretty new to using relationships like this, so it's highly likely I have something setup wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I forgot to add the method to the templates like so:

```
{{ $contacts->contact->fname }}
```